# Meteor react router rendering nothing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, react-router

I'm following this guide [Meteor React Routing](https://guide.meteor.com/react.html#routing) but unfortunately, my app now renders nothing (after adding routing, the app was working fine before-hand), and I can't see anything wrong

**App.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Navigation from './components/Navigation';
import LoginForm from './components/LoginForm';

export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
      return (
            <div>
                <Navigation />
                <p>
                    <h1>Something here</h1>
                </p>
        </div>
      );
    }
}
```

**main.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

import { renderRoutes } from './Routes.jsx';

Meteor.startup(() => {
  render(renderRoutes(), document.getElementById('app'));
});
```

**Routes.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route } from 'react-router';
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';

import App from '../imports/ui/App.jsx';
import LoginForm from '../imports/ui/components/LoginForm.jsx';

const browserHistory = createBrowserHistory();

export const renderRoutes = () => (
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
        <Route path="/login" component={LoginForm} />
    </Router>
);
```

**..and the html**

```
<head>
  <title>Some title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
</body>
```

I've verified that all imports resolve. And when running `meteor`, there are no errors. Nor are there any errors in the console of the browser, yet there is just a blank page. Have I missed something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there was an error that wasn't being thrown in Meteor. There was an issue with my Router definition, what it should actually be is:

```
export const renderRoutes = () => (
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <div>
            <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
            <Route path="/login" component={LoginForm} />
        </div>
    </Router>
);
```

Notice the inclusion of `div` - as it would appear that Router can only have one child element.

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning your routes.

It should be like below,

```
export const renderRoutes = () => (
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
        <Route path="/login" component={LoginForm} />
    </Router>
);

// or

export const renderRoutes = () => {
   return (
     <Router history={browserHistory}>
       <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
       <Route path="/login" component={LoginForm} />
    </Router>
   );
};
```

Comment: Thanks for spotting that, unfortunately even that change only renders blank pages also :(

Comment: @LokiSinclair can you try changing `render(renderRoutes(), document.getElementById('app'));` to `render(renderRoutes, document.getElementById('app'));`

Comment: That results in: "Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it." - Outputted to the console.